# Sorting generic set in swift

Tags: swift, sorting, generics, set

What is the correct way to sort a generic typed Set in swift?

```
class CustomSet<T: Hashable>: NSObject {
    var items: Set<T>

     init(_ items: [T]) {
        self.items = Set(items)
    }

    var toSortedArray: [T] {
        //Error: Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'T' operands
        return items.sort{ (a: T, b: T) -> Bool in return a < b}
    }
}
```

Xcode Version 7.1 beta (7B60), this is a wrapper around swifts `Set` type.

`items.sort{$0 < $1}` doesn't work

`Cannot invoke 'sort' with an argument list of type '((_, _) -> _)'`.

But works in `xcrun swift`

```
  1> let s = Set([4,2,3,4,6])
s: Set<Int> = {
  [0] = 6
  [1] = 2
  [2] = 4
  [3] = 3
}
  2> s.sort{$0 < $1}
$R0: [Int] = 4 values {
  [0] = 2
  [1] = 3
  [2] = 4
  [3] = 6
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to constrain your generic placeholder to conform to Comparable (as well as Hashable, which you are already doing). Otherwise, as the error message says, we cannot guarantee that `<` is applicable.

```
class CustomSet<T: Hashable where T:Comparable>: NSObject {
```

Your `xcrun` example works because Int *does* conform to Comparable.

Comment: That did it. I had tried `class CustomSet<T: Hashable, Comparable>`

Comment: The reason `<T: Hashable, Comparable>` doesn't work is that it means two placeholders, one called `T`, one called `Comparable`. The only way to do multiple constraints is a `where` clause. See the "Additional Constraints" section of my online Swift book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_additional_constraints